# Mongoose has variable defined as a number, but value in req.query is in quotes. How do I handle that?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Not that experienced in Node/Mongoose yet.

Given a browser query like this:

```
www.example.com/systems?properties.max_diameter=24
```

and that the Mongoose schema is:

```
var SystemSchema = new Schema({
    ....
    properties:       {
        max_diameter: { type: Number,  required: true}
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('System',  SystemSchema);
```

Using console.log(req.query), I know the Node controller sees:

```
req.query = { 'properties.max_diameter': '24' }
```

Note the value is in single quotes.

So, this query fails:

```
System.find(req.query).sort(sort_param).find(function(err, systems) {        
    res.send(systems);
});
```

But if I hard code the value so that I have this:

```
System.find({'properties.max_diameter': 24}).sort(sort_param).find(function(err, systems) {        
    res.send(systems);
});
```

It works perfectly fine.

Of course, removing quotes is easy, but I can't possibly know the various query combinations that will be used. I thought that Mongoose would somehow handle that, but I can't figure out what I am missing or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers.

Comment: Mongoose does this casting for you based on the schema definition.  There's something else going on here.

Comment: You should be using `exec` instead of the second `find`, but that's just an aside as it works for me either way.

Comment: JohnnyHK - do you have an example of the casting in this context? I can find examples for validation checks etc, or saves, but not for casting req.query. There must be an elegant way to handle this.

Comment: There's nothing you need to do for the casting.  I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, but try and simplify things  to provide code that reproduces the problem without `req.query` and I'll bet you find the actual problem.

Comment: I am thinking it is because we have Mongoose only installed - and not this: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-api-query Will try in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm sure you know, the request comes over as a string in the body of the HTTP request. Which means that you need to convert your string representation of the number to a number object before submitting to Mongoose. I can understand why you would feel Mongoose would do this automatically, but I can think of several use cases where the opposite effect would be desired. Though most projects use Mongoose along side an HTTP server, you could use Mongoose to write many other types of apps.

To solve the problem, simply use `parseInt()` inside your route to convert to a number object before using the `req.query` object for your search.

```
req.body.max_diameter = parseInt(req.max_diameter);

System.find(req.query).sort(sort_param).find(function(err, systems) {        
  res.send(systems);
});
```

You could also setup a middleware function to handle this globally for you.